# Python - input from list of tuples

Tags: python

I've declared a list of tuples that I would like to manipulate. I have a function that returns an option from the user. I would like to see if the user has entered any one of the keys 'A', 'W', 'K'. With a dictionary, I would say this: `while option not in author.items() option = get_option()`. How can I accomplish this with a list of tuples?

```
authors = [('A', "Aho"), ('W', "Weinberger"), ('K', "Kernighan")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
authors = [('A', "Aho"), ('W', "Weinberger"), ('K', "Kernighan")]
option = get_option()
while option not in (x[0] for x in authors):
    option = get_option()
```

How this works :

`(x[0] for x in authors)` is an generator expression, this yield the `[0]th` element of each item one by one from authors list, and that element is then matched against the `option`. As soon as match is found it short-circuits and exits.

Generator expressions yield one item at a time, so are memory efficient.

Comment: I just initialized option = '' prior to the loop, then once inside I received option. This helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: +1 the list comp. is far nicer than the `zip(*iter)[0]` solution.

Comment: To get the name associated with option would I need to print authors[option]?

Comment: @Dford.py No You can't do that here, you've to do a liner search again to get the name. `name = next(x[1] for x in authors if x[0] == option)`

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
option in zip(*authors)[0]
```

We are using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to essentially separate the letters from the words. Nevertheless, since we are dealing with a *list* of tuples, we must [unpack](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) it using `*`:

```
>>> zip(*authors)
[('A', 'W', 'K'), ('Aho', 'Weinberger', 'Kernighan')]
>>> zip(*authors)[0]
('A', 'W', 'K')
```

Then we simply use `option in` to test if option is contained in `zip(*authors)[0]`.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how to use this, could explain this a little more?

Comment: `zip` will return [a list of tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), which you can then iterate over like any other iterable.  That does mean that the syntax here is a bit incomplete, though.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not sure I see what the problem is.

Comment: @Dford.py I added a little more of an explanation.

Comment: @arshajii I appreciate that, thanks a lot. if I wanted to inspect the input of option would I only need to specify it like this: if option == 'A': # then do something

Comment: @Dford.py Yes, if you wanted to test whether `option` contains a specific value.

Comment: If you wanted the complete syntax, then it'd be either `(option for option in zip(*authors)[0])` (to get a generator), or `[option for option in zip(*authors)[0]]` (to get a list comprehension).

Comment: @Makoto I assumed `option` was the variable in which the user stores some input.

Answer (score 0):

There are good answers here that cover doing this operation with `zip`, but you don't *have* to do it like that - you can use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
authors = OrderedDict([('A', "Aho"), ('W', "Weinberger"), ('K', "Kernighan")])
```

Since it remembers its entry order, you can iterate over it without fear of getting odd or unusual orderings of your keys.